# What is the proper OpenGraph markup for an image?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

The [OpenGraph documentation](http://ogp.me/) provides a "full image example":

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

However, this conflicts with the opening salvo that mentions the following properties are required:

```
og:title
og:type
og:image
og:url
```

So, is something like this also required?

```
<meta property="og:type" content="???" />
```

Or is the `og:type` somehow implicitly no longer required when `og:image` properties are present? Or does `og:image:type` somehow magically supplant the explicit requirement for `og:type'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've rightly noted a bug in the protocol as is. Based on the docs, it sounds like a consensus on `og:type` for image has yet to be reached.

Looking at [what Instagram does for their images](http://instagram.com/p/lszr6HrKL8/) It looks like you'll need to implement a custom namespaced type.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="instapp:photo" />
```

There's some info speaking to this directly [in the spec](http://ogp.me/):

> When the community agrees on the schema for a type, it is added to the
>   list of global types. All other objects in the type system are CURIEs
>   of the form
>
> `<head prefix="my_namespace: http://example.com/ns#">`
>   `<meta property="og:type" content="my_namespace:my_type" />`
>
> The global types
>   are grouped into verticals. Each vertical has its own namespace. The
>   og:type values for a namespace are always prefixed with the namespace
>   and then a period. This is to reduce confusion with user-defined
>   namespaced types which always have colons in them.